# batch file kill multiple programs on text file

Tags: text, batch-file, keyboard, kill

I am looking for a batch file to kill all programs listed on a text file this would be very useful

also i am looking for a batch file to link an exe or bat to a keyboard shortcut

Example would be when you click ctrl 5 to launch ie but the bat must link it to the keys

Justin

Comment: nothing so far i was thinking of using the for command

Comment: FOR /F is definitely a good start. You will also need TASKKILL. Why don't you take a stab at writing it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEXTFILE.TXT`

```
notepad.exe
iexplore.exe
chrome.exe
```

`KILLIST.BAT`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (textfile.txt) do taskkill /IM %%x
```

Keep in mind that if there are multiple instances of the same program open that without more information than the name of the executable that `taskkill.exe` will simply kill the first instance it encounters, probably the first one opened.

A more exact method is to use the window name (even just a portion of it), use `tasklist.exe` to search for that, grab the PID (Process ID), **then** use `taskill.exe /PID ####` to kill that exact process.

Another choice would be to kill **ALL** the programs with the same file-name. Doing that could also be done by collecting PID's but is simpler to just 'count' them and kill them that way. (It's not really counting, but it's close.)

`TEXTFILE.TXT`

```
notepad.exe
iexplore.exe
chrome.exe
```

`KILLIST.BAT`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (textfile.txt) do (
  for /f "skip=3" %%y in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%x"') do (
    taskkill /IM %%y
  )
)
```

---

**==================================================================================**

**EDIT:** 2012/09/07

To create a keyboard short-cut for the batch file, you need to:

1) Open `Windows Explorer` and browse to where you have the batch file located.
2) `Right Click` -> `KILLIST.BAT` -> `Create shortcut`
3) `Right Click` -> `KILLIST.BAT - Shortcut` -> `Rename`
4) Delete `- Shortcut` -> Press `[ENTER]`
5) `Right Click` -> the new `KILLIST.BAT` -> `Properties`
6) `Select` -> the `Shortcut` tab
7) `Click` -> the box next to `Shortcut Key:`
8) `Press` -> the keys you want to make the shortcut from. (It will display them)
9) `Click` -> `OK`

You can do this with any shorcut, not just ones for a batch file.

For this method to work, you must keep the shortcut on the Desktop or in your Start Menu somewhere.

A better choice would be a **Macro Generator** like [AutoHotkey](http://download.cnet.com/AutoHotkey-L/3000-2084_4-10279446.html?tag=mncol;1).

Comment: Thank you very much it worked like a charm and you explained it well what about the keyboard shotcut?

Comment: I've added an explanation of how to create a keyboard shortcut, but it dates back to Windows 95 days (possibly even Windows 3.1, I don't recall) and is not reliable. Download a macro generator instead, many of them can do more than just play back keystrokes and mouse clicks.

Comment: Actually, it is reliable,  it just needs to be on the desktop or start menu.